# Choosing the train data size automatically - Sarimax Time Series Model

Tags: time-series, distributions, arima

I am working on a forecasting application on some credit data. The flow of money looks as follows:

[image: Time Series]

I am using a `sarimax` model since I have weekly seasonality. For choosing the parameters (p, q, d and P, Q, D) automatically, I am using [pmdarima](https://github.com/alkaline-ml/pmdarima). There are 500 points (one datapoint each day) to train and 50 to test. When I trained with all 500 instances, my AIC values shown during `auto_arima` train are around 16000 and my model performance, determined by MAE on the test data, is not great.

However, when I reduced the train data size (to only use the past 4 months), I can see that the AIC values have come down to 2000 range and my models are performing much better on the test set.

I can also see that the data from train with only the past 4 months looks much more similar in distribution to the test data from these plots.

[image: KDE Plot of all training data and test data]
[image: KDE Plot of only past 4 months of training data and test data]

However, the AIC values might have gone down just because the dataset size is less.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to automatically determine what would be the ideal dataset size (n months back into the past) for training?
2. Would it make sense to do a transformation to the data (like log) before applying my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear from your plots, but it looks like the upper histogram is the entire 500-day data series, and the lower histogram is the 4-month restricted series.

Question 1 I don't think can be answered because it seems like backwards thinking. Your model with more data is performing poorly on the test set because the test set is only representative of the last 4 months of your data. Your model with only 4 months of data is performing well on the test set because the test set is more representative of that data.

At this point you need to stop and consider *why* this is happening, using your knowledge of the problem domain. Does your test data selection procedure need to be revised? Did something change 4 months ago that would cause the distribution of the data to change? Do you have reason to believe that the distribution will change in the future? Does it make sense for your problem to only train on data from the last 4 months?

You also need to consider how the model is to be used, and if/when it will be re-trained in the future. Will this be automatically re-fit every weekend, or is this an ad-hoc model for a one-off task? How far in the future will you need to make forecasts?

Question 2 is a "probably not". Log transformation is usually good for when your data lives across several orders of magnitude; that doesn't look to be the case based on your first chart. Your data also looks to be censored at 0, so you also need to consider what to do with the 0-value points, since $\log(0)$ is not defined.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.

Yes - The first plot represents the entire history and the lower histogram is the 4 months. I had put up an image description but somehow that is not being shown.

Thank you for pointing me to the right questions as well. Unfortunately, I do not have much domain information at this point - all I have is this univariate time series. But I will definitely look into this. 

The model will be re-trained weekly. So, I am assuming that using only the past few months during training would work better.